# Programa com em loop While, try e except (python)

Tags: python, loop, while

"Escreva um programa que lê repetitivamente números até que o usuário digite “pronto”. Quando “pronto” for digitado, mostre a soma total, a quantidade e a média dos números digitados. Se o usuário digitar qualquer coisa que não seja um número, detecte o erro usando o try e o except e mostre na tela uma mensagem de erro e pule para o próximo número."

Eu consigo escrever parte do programa, mas não estou conseguindo sair do loop.

eu tentei varias alterações no código que eu estava fazendo, um dos códigos que tentei foi esse:

```
while True:
    try:
        inp_numero = int(input('Digite um numero:'))
        if inp_numero == 'pronto':
            break
    except:
        print('Entrada invalida')
sum(inp_numero)
```

eu não terminei a parte para somar, contar e fazer a media.

Em resumo, não estou conseguindo criar um código que eu consiga que o programa detecte uma string como um erro (retornando uma entrada invalida e continuando a rodar o programa) ao mesmo tempo que saia do loop quando o usuário digitar um "pronto". E depois como fazer para aproveitar (somar, contar e fazer a media) apenas das entradas numéricas.

Answer (score 0):

Bem, você está convertendo a string para um int na linha 3. A string 'pronto' não pode ser convertida para um inteiro logo, está dando erro. Você pode resolver assim

```
while True:
    try:
        inp = input('Digite um numero:')
        if inp == 'pronto':
          break
        else:
          inp_numero = int(inp)
    except:
        print('Entrada invalida')
sum(inp_numero)
```

Comment: `sum(inp_numero)`? Esta implementação não faz muito sentido, e dá erro: `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: Lucas, muito obrigado pela ajuda, eu consegui entender melhor depois que vc me ajudou, eu estava achando que daria para colocar direto, convertendo ja na pergunta para (int). Eu li outros documentos e consegui terminar minha formula.